# Count number of occurences of a character in SQL string value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If you have the e-mail address

```
you.late.you@asdf.com

you_late_you@asdf.com
```

How are you enable to count if you have 2 dots/underscore by using sql code?

Comment: Do you want to be able to count the number of dots and underscores?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select len('you.late.you@asdf.com') - len(replace('you.late.you@asdf.com', '.', ''))
```

Comment: it will not count both of them

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You are right. It is not clear what the OP wants. Counting them seperately or adding them.

Answer (score 1):

this will give you the desired result.

```
 DECLARE @str VARCHAR(1000)
SET @str = 'you.l_ate.you@as_df.com'
SELECT (LEN(@str)- LEN(REPLACE(@str ,'.' ,'')))+(LEN(@str)- LEN(REPLACE(@str ,'_' ,'')))
```

answer : 5

Answer (score 1):

I think he wants to count the letters without the dots before the @:

```
declare @myEmail varchar(50)
set @myEmail = 'you.late.you@asdf.com'

declare @mySearch varchar(50)
set @mySearch = SUBSTRING (@myEmail,0 , PATINDEX( '%@%',@myEmail))
select (LEN(REPLACE(@mySearch, '.', '')))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of rows that have two `.` or `_`, you could do the following:

```
select count(*) 
  from mytable 
 where left(email, charindex('@', email)) like '%[._]%[._]%'
```

The `left` and `charindex` is used to disregard the domain name (which will have `.`).

Reference: [LIKE (TSQL, SQL Server 2008)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    length(substr('you.late.you@asdf.com',1,INSTR('you.late.you@asdf.com','@',1))) - 
    length(replace(substr('you.late.you@asdf.com',1,INSTR('you.late.you@asdf.com','@',1)), '.', '')) 
from dual
```